# Mosfet Driver - High Side Output Problem

Tags: mosfet, driver, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, low-side

I've been trying to make a 3 phase inverter to drive a BLDC motor.

Mosfets : IRF3205

Driver   : IR2101

Supply voltage for FETs and drivers : 12V

BLDC : https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Seeed%20Technology/108990010_Web.pdf

I wrote a simple code for Arduino Uno. I change firing sequence of the MOSFETs manually, based on the figure given.
 [image]

Arduino reads the voltage from the potantiometer and creates frequency range between 15Hz-60Hz in terms of revolution. Duty cycle is 1/3.

The Code:

```
 int AA1=7;
 int AA2=6;
 int BB1=5;
 int BB2=4;
 int CC1=3;
 int CC2=2;
 int IN=A0;


 void setup() {

  pinMode(AA1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(AA2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BB1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BB2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CC1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CC2,OUTPUT);

}

 void loop() {

 int t =analogRead(IN); //From the potentiometer
 Delay=map(t,0,1024,10000,3000); //we obtain the delay speed using the 
potentiometer


  digitalWrite(AA1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(AA2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(BB1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(CC2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(BB2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CC1,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(Delay);

  digitalWrite(AA2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(BB1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(CC1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(CC2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(AA1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(BB2,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(Delay);

  digitalWrite(AA2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(BB1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(BB2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(CC1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(CC2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(AA1,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(Delay);

  digitalWrite(AA1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(AA2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(BB2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(CC1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(BB1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CC2,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(Delay);

  digitalWrite(AA1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(BB2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(CC1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(CC2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(AA2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(BB1,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(Delay);


  digitalWrite(AA1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(BB1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(BB2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(CC2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(CC1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(AA2,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(Delay);
```

}

The problem is there is no PWM signal output at the high side whereas low side has a PWM output. So, the motor does not turn, it just vibrates but not even goes one step.

I calculated the value for bootstrap capacitor and found that around 200-300nF. I think the problem has to do with bootstrapping and I've tried different capacitor values : 220nF, 4.7uF(including electrolyte), 10uF(including electrolyte), 2.2uF(including electrolyte) so far. However, none of them has not worked.

There is only a DC voltage near to 10Vdc at the high side of the driver. When I change capacitors, it's ripple changes but I can't see PWM output.

What could cause the problem ?
Thanks.

Here is my circuit : [image]

Comment: You're not doing anything to generate a PWM. Your code generates the six steps, and each one is fully on for the duration. Since you have no ramp-up to minimum speed, it may be that the motor is failing to get in synchronization with the switching of the bridge.

Comment: *There is only a DC voltage at the high side of the driver.* Is it 0Vdc of 12Vdc or something in between? Please share values, or better: scope images.

Comment: @Huisman, it is not 0Vdc, close to 10Vdc.

Answer (score 1):

I would debug this in two separate pieces, starting with the following ...

1. As you're doing six-step commutation, you can should verify that you can command a commutation state on your Arduino and you see the right outputs on the six PWM outputs. Be sure you review typical six-step commutation strategies ... where you basically have three states: PWM, ON and OFF (high impedance)
2. Drive a single pre-driver and bootstrap with a function generator. Do you see the same behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Use 10k gate pull-down resistors for the low side MOSFET. Maybe your low side MOSFETs are not turning off properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have damaged the 1N4148 diodes by arbitrary trying bootstraps capacitors.
The current through the bootstrap diode is limited by the ESR of the cap and \$R_{DSon}\$, so, hardly nothing limits the current. Depending on brand, the 1N4148 can handle a surge current of 1 to 2A.
Start by checking these diodes.

Next, you'd better *calculate* what bootstrap capacitor you require.
Check for example: [Chapter 3 Bootstrap Components Selection](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua887/slua887.pdf)
Or: [Chapter 3. How to select the bootstrap components](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-978.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559f7cf21200)
(I think it should be in the order of 200 - 300nF, but I don't know the switching frequency).
Do add a bootstrap resistor to protect the bootstrap diode at start-up.

Moreover, do also add a 10 nF as close as possible to each IR2101's power pins. And replace C1, C3 and C5 by about 1uF or 2.2uF *ceramic* capacitors (about 10x the bootstrap capacitor value). They should be second closest to the IR2101.

PS. I didn't check the code. Since you're claiming the low side is PWM'ing, I think the bootstrap circuit should be fixed first.

Comment: "I think it should be in the order of 200 - 300nF". Yes I had calculated the value and it is between 200nF-300nF. I've checked the diodes and they work.

Comment: If you know the value, why not share it? This way, it stays vague.